# Rfc2898DeriveBytes with Sha2 in C#

Tags: c#, password-encryption, sha2

I have a password hashing mechanism based upon Rfc2898DeriveBytes (based on code detailed here: http://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm).  Internally, this class utilizes SHA1 which - the CrackStation link does indicate the SHA1 is "old", but also states that, although Rfc2898DeriveBytes uses it internally, Rfc2898DeriveBytes is still a good mechanism.

The security department of a customer of mine has heard that that "SHA1 has been compromised" (specifically, that, for purposes of signing a document for transmission across the internet, SHA1 has been defeated, under certain circumstances - the fact that this "vulnerability" does not apply to a password hash is immaterial to the security department).  As a result, they have demanded that we alter our password hashing mechanism to employ SHA2.

Currently, the .Net framework has no equivalent of Rfc2898DeriveBytes that employs SHA2 (or SHA256, etc.) internally.  I know that I can use reflection to get at the source code for this class and change it, but I've always been told that the first rule of encryption is "don't grow your own".

This is principally a political demand by my customer, not a technical one, which could be easily satisfied by running the password through a SHA2 hash prior to running it through Rfc2898DeriveBytes.  However, I am not sufficiently knowledgeable about cryptography to know if this might be bad - might in fact result in an objectively less secure password hash.

Does anyone know of an Rfc2898DeriveBytes equivalent class that employs SHA2?  Or, does anyone know if running the password through a SHA2 hash prior to Rfc2898DeriveBytes would be perfectly safe?

Answer (score 0):

Download the free code samples from "[SecurityDriven.NET](http://securitydriven.net/)" book. Find the **PBKDF2** class which takes an **HMAC** factory. Available factories include **SHA2** (**256**, **384**, **512**).

Running the password through **SHA2** hash prior to `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` is *not* the right thing to do, even if this is unlikely to be the weakest part of whatever you're doing (you'd be losing password entropy).